# Un-attach footer from the bottom of the browser

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning, footer

I coded my footer ages ago and I can figure out what I did to attach it to the bottom of the browser and stop the page scrolling. What I want is for the footer to be below the #main div so you have to scroll down to see it.

I apologise for my messy code, and for asking this tedious question

Arran,16

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/home.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to do:

1. Remove "position:fixed" from your #footer
2. Add "clear:both" to it

That should work, I think.

Comment: hm, that shouldn't have happened, I think. Tried checking your link again, but it's not working. Does that mean you've fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed` and `bottom: 0` from your `#footer` element, so footer will be,

```
#header {
    height: 110px;
    width: auto;
}
```